# Print Value of Key in Lists of Dicts in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to print the value of a specific key in a list of dicts:

eg:

```
list = [{'a' : 123, 'b': 'xyz', 'c': [1,2]}, {'a' : 456, 'b': 'cde', 'c': [3,4]}]
```

I was hoping to be able to print the following for each dict:

```
print ("a: ", a)
print ("b: ", b)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about some nested loops, to avoid hard-coding it?

```
for dictionary in list: # rename list so you don't overshadow the builtin list
    for key in ('a', 'b'):
        print(key + ':', dictionary[key])
```

which should output:

```
a: 123
b: xyz
a: 456
b: cde
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're guaranteed those keys exist, a nice solution using [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

# Renamed your list; don't name variables list
for a, b in map(itemgetter('a', 'b'), mylist):
    print("a:", a)
    print("b:", b)
```

The above is just a slightly optimized version of the import free code, pushing the work of fetching values to the builtins instead of doing it over and over yourself.

```
for d in mylist:  # Renamed your list; don't name variables list
    print("a:", d['a'])
    print("b:", d['b'])
```

Oh, and for completeness (Aaron Hall is right that it's nice to avoid redundant code), a tweak to `itemgetter` usage to observe DRY rules:

```
keys = ('a', 'b')
for values in map(itemgetter(*keys), mylist):
    for k, v in zip(keys, values):
        print(k, v, sep=": ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [{'a' : 123, 'b': 'xyz', 'c': [1,2]}, {'a' : 456, 'b': 'cde', 'c': [3,4]}]
output=['a','b']
for dct in lst:
    for k in output:
        print(k+': '+str(dct[k]))
```